# HTTP 302 Redirect on contextRoot

Tags: jboss

I don't understand why my Jboss 7.1 is doing a redirect on my contextRoot.

When I visit "localhost:8080/myContext/",
it does a 302 redirect to "localhost:8080/myContext/myContext/.

I have tried to deploy my war on another Jboss and it doesn't have that problem. 
Any ideas?

**jboss-web.xml:**

```
       <jboss-web>
         <!-- <security-domain>java:/jaas/NeptuneRealm</security-domain> -->
         <context-root>webNeptune</context-root>
       </jboss-web>
```

**web.xml**

```
   <module-name>webNeptune</module-name>
```

I m looking for this problem, but I found nothing in my jboss configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Add a '/' in your context-root and you can remove the `<module-name>` element from web.xml

```
<jboss-web>
    <context-root>/webNeptune</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```